# How to config the heron-core file in Heron 0.17.5 version?

Tags: heron

When I used heron 0.17.1 version, I can config the heron-core file as following:

```
# location of the core package
heron.package.core.uri:                      "/heron/dist/heron-core.tar.gz"

# Whether role/env is required to submit a topology. Default value is False.
heron.config.is.role.required:               True
heron.config.is.env.required:                True
```

In this config, I deployed Heron 0.17.1 version with HDFS as its Uploader. So I copied the local file /heron/dist/heron-core.tar.gz file to hdfs://heron/disk in HDFS, and it worked. 
However, when I updated the Heron's version from 0.17.1 to 0.17.5, I found there is no heron-core.tar.gz file in local /heron/dist directory. But it still needs to config the heron-core.tar.gz url in Client.yaml:

```
# location of the core package
# heron.package.core.uri:                      "file:///vagrant/.herondata/dist/heron-core-release.tar.gz"

# Whether role/env is required to submit a topology. Default value is False.
heron.config.is.role.required:               True
heron.config.is.env.required:                True
```

So what should I do to config the heron-core url in Client.yaml when I using Heron 0.17.5 verion? In detail, I tested the Heron cluster that didn't config the heron-core url, and it didn't work. You can see the change of Heron version in 0.17.5 is [#2684](https://github.com/apache/incubator-heron/pull/2684). 
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: you can try to configure "heron.package.core.uri" in `scheduler.yaml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I found there is no core-core.tar.gz file in local /heron/dist directory.". You mean "heron-core.tar.gz"? I checked the centos build (https://github.com/apache/incubator-heron/releases/download/0.17.5/heron-0.17.5-centos.tar.gz) and I believe heron-core.tar.gz is in the dist directory.

Comment: Sorry for that. Yes, I mean "heron-core.tar.gz" file. When I installed heron with version 0.17.1, I can find the heron-core.tar.gz file at {HERON_HOME}/.heron/dist directory. But there is no heron-core.tar.gz after installed Heron with 0.17.5. However, as you said, I can find the heron-core.tar.gz in "heron-0.17.5-ubuntu.tar.gz", so I will try to copy the file to HDFS and config the heron.core.url in client.yaml.